# sharing /data file between two android application

Tags: android, android-ndk

My requirement is to share some  txt file between two application. One application is writing in that text file and other application is reading in the native code file native cpp/c file handling calling.

Now the the file which is created by application 1 is having 777 file permission and only the application 2 can access the file in native. Is there any way for application 1 to  create that file with properly permission for application2.

Comment: Yes you can create this kind of functionality using `Content Provider` and by making `Content Provider` application @YSBhai

Comment: @GrlsHu problem is using ContentProvider i can share db not txt files